# problem in updating Opera browser

Tags: updates, deb, browser, opera

I'm a new user of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS). I want to update my Opera browser, but I have this problem:

**My Opera version is 46.0.2597.57 and the new version 47.0.2631.55 is available, but when I want to update my Opera it says: opera-stable is already the newest version (46.0.2597.57), but IT IS NOT!**

I did this:

- `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/stable non-free'`
- `wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install opera-stable`

and the response was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
opera-stable is already the newest version (46.0.2597.57).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

what is the problem with it?

thank you in advance :-)

---

NOTE: I've downloaded *opera-stable_47.0.2631.55_amd64.deb* and tried to install it by Ubuntu Software, but it didn't work!

Comment: Try installing your `deb` package using `sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_47.0.2631.55_amd64.deb`

Comment: … or just click the `.deb` file to install the package. It will also automatically configure your package sources for automated updates, see [here](http://deb.opera.com/manual.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already downloaded the `.deb` package, just click it and the installation will start. Alternatively do in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_47.0.2631.55_amd64.deb
```

They way you wanted to do it of course also works, but you forgot the first step. However, this is totally unnecessary if you install the `.deb` package directly, as it will add the repository automatically.

1. add the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free'
   ```
2. add the key:

   ```
   wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. update your sources:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install opera-stable
   ```

Comment: But, I didn't forget the first step! I forgot to writ it here :)) 
And 
CLICK to install Didn't work too! When the installation started, Suddenly the Ubuntu Software switched installation to Opera 46.0.2597.57!!! And I don't know why!?

But your second advice (by terminal) worked! Thanks :) 
(I still don't know why just that way works for me!)